# Foreach not working in php and Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to do a foreach loop in php and jquery for multiple select but all i am getting to echo out is Array.

**html**

```
<select multiple="multiple" class="select tagz" required>
```

**php**

```
if(!empty($_POST['tagz'])){
            $tag = $_POST['tagz']);

            foreach($tag as $tagz){
            echo $tagz;
            }

        }else{
            echo "Please select tags";
        }
```

**Jquery**

```
function serealizeSelects (select)
        {
            var array = [];
            select.each(function(){ array.push($(this).val()) });
            return array;
        }
        var tagz = serealizeSelects($(".tagz"));
$.post('upload.php', {tagz:tagz, title:title, category:category, description:description, price:price}, function(data){

            $('#confirm').html(data);

        });
```

Please tell me what i am doing wrong

Comment: Your select element is not named therefor `$_POST['tagz']` is empty.

Comment: php and jquery (javascript) are two different worlds ... the php is running on your server ... the javascript is running on your browser ..

Comment: @subby3 you have doing many typo mistake check in my ans

Comment: @Wobbles please let them check,i think you didn't specify $tag = $_POST['tagz']); to $tag = $_POST['tagz'];

Comment: @ParthChavda I think you are trying to refer to a typo with an additional unneeded closing parenthesis. Your explanation is unclear as you are asking him to rename something, not correct a typo/syntax error.

Comment: if you think something is helpful but not clear explanation so you can edit my ans.it's my pleasure if you make me correct @Wobbles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing `select.each(function(){ array.push($(this).val()) });`
but select variable contains only the select element and each has no meaning.You need to use `each` in the options.So change your selector.

```
           var tagz = serealizeSelects($(".tagz option"));
```

or if you dont want to change the selector just use find to find all options inside your select

```
           select.find('option').each(function(){ array.push($(this).val()) })
```

Of course i cannot know where you define your other variables.If you have other problems too just show me your whole javascript code so I can help you more.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get a post variable for a field named `tagz`, but you do not have a field named `tagz` (at least not in the code you have provided).

Consider changing the HTML to this:

```
<select name="tagz" multiple="multiple" class="select tagz" required>
```